# How can I use a PHP variable in view2.php which has been defined in view1.php in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two views view1.php and view2.php in CodeIgniter and I have included view2.php in view1.php and I want to use the value of variable $user_update in view2.php which I have defined in view1.php.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just pass it to the view as you'd do in a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading view2 within view1.. you can use the following code.

Within view1.php:

```
$this->load->view('view2', array('your_variable' => $your_variable));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a loader.

```
$this->load->vars($array);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html